# setAttribute on click with parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to execute my function on buttons with parameters.

Here is my function :

```
addkibanaCards(devices, _kiban_links.pm10_link_light, '24h', 'quick');
```

Trying to do it by setting attribute `onclick`, but still having errors.
How can I correctly do it in way as below?

```
setButtons: function(prefix) {
  document.getElementById('7d').setAttribute("onclick", "addkibanaCards(" + devices + "," + prefix + "," + '24h' + "," + 'quick' + ")");
}
```

Comment: Assigning to the `onclick` attribute is essentially `eval` inside of HTML markup. Never use it.

Comment: It even says under the `javascript-events` tag **DO NOT USE THIS TAG** !

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach event handler instead of `setAttribute()`

```
 document.getElementById('7d').addEventListener("click", function () {
    addkibanaCards(devices, prefix, '24h', 'quick');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) with `click` instead of `onclick` and with [Arrow function (=>)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) like the following:

```
document.getElementById('7d').addEventListener("click", () => addkibanaCards(devices, _kiban_links.pm10_link_light, '24h', 'quick'));
```